# Can anyone explain to me why my code isn't return anything into the terminal

Tags: python

For some reason the terminal keeps returning nothing, not even a value of `none`. I would appreciate some enlightenment on the matter.

```
import requests
import json
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
 
def monitor():
    source = requests.get ('https://www.topps.com')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content,'lxml')
    for hrefs in soup.find_all('figure', class_='product-item-link'):
        url = "https://www.tops.com/cards-collectibles/topps-now" + hrefs.a.get('href')
        print(url)

monitor()
```

Comment: please make sure your code is properly indented. It also looks like you have some imports that aren't shown.

Your code also has no `return`, so there is no way it would return anything. Perhaps you mean printed

Comment: The value of hrefs in the link is most likely empty, try running `print(soup.find_all('figure', class_='product-item-link')` before the loop to make sure the list is not empty before entering the loop.

Comment: I'll make an assumption about how this should be indented and say that the issue is simply that soup.find_all() is returning an empty list. EDIT: I've just tested your code and that's exactly what's happening

Comment: Can i get some insight on how to make the list full? Im trying to make it where the bot makes a list of the preexisting data before it hard since I am a beginner

Comment: Actually, it's simpler than I'd originally commented. You forget to check the response from the GET request. You'll note that it's returning HTTP 503. Normally that means "Server unavailable" however, in this case it looks like the site is blocking "scrapers"

Comment: so are you suggesting i use a proxy or fake user module